# Реальные способы определения адреса по IP?

Tags: ip, ip-address

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие есть варианты определения реального(город, улица, дом) адреса владельца IP и реально ли это вообще?

Comment: Без общения с провайдером-владельцем айпишника — нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Максимум это город. Иногда можно узнать провайдера , а уже основывая из данных в каком районе находится провайдер. 
Пример город Киев , на моем районе есть провайдер о3,  nashnet. 
А в Киеве есть крупные провайдера типа Воля , Киевстар.

Провайдера можно узнать у гугла . И уже основываясь из этих данных можно сузить круг поиска.

Answer (score 0):

Почти каждый провайдер использует динамическую выдачу IP адресов. Поэтому узнать точно местоположение не получится.